# Filesystem root '/' should be owned by 'hdfs' shows when configuration with hue

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hue

Here is my settings

[image]

But it shows error message like this

```
Current value: http://master ip:50070/webhdfs/v1
Filesystem root '/' should be owned by 'hdfs'
```

Comment: Are the hue user has access to the hdfs cluster?

Comment: Thanks, I found that I can set the user name under thie file
desktop/libs/hadoop/src/hadoop/fs/webhdfs.py

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changing the code is not good approach
You can change in config file in 'hue/desktop/conf/pseudo-distributed.ini'
under [desktop] section

```
 default_hdfs_superuser=hdfs

          to  

 default_hdfs_superuser=hduser
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified the "DEFAULT_HDFS_SUPERUSER" name to my current user name under

desktop/libs/hadoop/src/hadoop/fs/webhdfs.py